# Nano Electric Receiver Switch - Circuit Components

Tags: switches, pwm, circuit-analysis, remote-control, reverse-engineering

I want to recreate the circuit board below, but I am having a hard time figuring out what components I need. I have been trying to look them up on mouser but I haven't got any results.

It is called the [NERS V2](http://www.hansenhobbies.com/products/onboardacc/ers/nersv2/), the board uses a PWM signal from a remote control (RC) receiver to open or close a circuit. `1-2ms pulses at 50hz, where pulses > 1.5ms turns it on, and <1.5ms turns it off`

Does anyone know what these parts could be?

Heres the board, all components are on one side.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sounds like a smoother, comparator, and SSR.

Comment: [One down](http://www.ti.com/product/lp2985-50), two to go.

Comment: I have the device on me right now.

Comment: Can you create a schematic of the device, as well as collect voltages relative to ground from various points while the device is in operation?

Comment: Yes, I will try. I might have to desolder some components to get the schematic, so give me 30 miniutes

Comment: Don't desolder, just do continuity checks.

Comment: The instructions pdf has good info on the operation and theory and modifications. http://www.hansenhobbies.com/products/onboardacc/ers/nersv2/NERSV2.pdf `All modern RC systems send 1-2ms pulses at 50Hz to the servos to send positional data. The NERS switches from OFF to ON at 1.5ms (mid-stick), so that it is always OFF below 1.5ms, and always ON above 1.5ms`

Comment: Hence my original comment. It would make sense if the MN9 was a MOSFET/IGBT, and I can only imagine that the 00J1 is a pulse counter of some sort.

Comment: yes, also the two pins on OOJ1 can be jumped to ground to change functionality of the circuit as shown in the [pdf](http://www.hansenhobbies.com/products/onboardacc/ers/nersv2/NERSV2.pdf)

Comment: @AFerrara you are also missing the ground connection for the 00j1 ic.

Comment: I will check the continuity again, but I couldn't find a ground pin.. except for the one that goes through the cap

Comment: It's possible (though very unlikely) that one of those 5/6 pin devices is one of the really, really tiny PIC MCUs.

Comment: @ConnorWolf could be. From the pictures of the other products, they sanded off the label on one, and another had h900 or a900 or 006H (or some variation), while the last one has an 8 pin version, while all having the same general operation.

Comment: @ConnorWolf you are most likely right. I think it's a pic10f200.

Answer (score 2):

The LPSL is the [5v regulator LP2985-50](http://www.ti.com/product/lp2985-50) that allows the circuit to work at a better voltage range then the PERS (Another version of the receiver switch that the manufacturer offers) 2-6v range.

The MN9 X1 is a N Channel Mosfet similar to Diodes Inc [DMN2041L-7](http://www.diodes.com/datasheets/ds31962.pdf).
The X1 is a Year/Month Code.

The 00J1 is most likely a [Microchip PIC10F200 microcontroller](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001239E.pdf), based on the number code 00J1 (00 is product, as in F200, J1 is a tracing code, like lot/bin/manufacturing number). 256 word code size, 16bytes ram, 4 I/O (1 input only) with 1 8-bit timer. The voltage range of 2~6v of the NERS is close to the 2~5.5v of the PIC10F200. Also, the pinout as you have shown, is very much the same, with pin 2 being ground and pin 5 being V+.

The code emulates a servo control circuit. It monitors pin 1 for a pulse between 1ms and 2ms every 20ms (50hz), then toggles pin 3 based on what it receives (Anything longer than 1.54ms switches it to On, anything less than 1.46ms switches it to Off). Pin 4 and pin 2 can be used for features, like the reverse output, and safety operation.

That's all it does. You could do the same with any microcontroller. [This site](http://www.robotsimple.com/index.php?route=product/search&keyword=rc%20switch) has three versions using the same basic idea (Pic10f2xx reading signals, mosfet or direct gpio out)

[This is a similar project](http://myweb.tiscali.co.uk/kendo/rc_switch/html/start.html), using a pic12f, with schematic and code.

Comment: So what about the 00J1?

Comment: @AFerrara Not sure. Just wanted to add what we had. As conner had speculated in the comments that it could be a microcontroller, because considering the chip has three inputs and one output, with pulse counting. It's almost like the way a servo controller works.

Comment: @AFerrara updated.