# Is there such thing as a PWM Transistor?

Tags: transistors, pwm

I have a 7-channel RC receiver that outputs PWM at 5V. One of the channels is controlled by a simple switch (on/off) on the transmitter.

I'd like to use this switch to control a 24V device. The problem is that this device only accepts binary input (no PWM). Even when the PWM is considered "off", there is still that little spike on the oscilloscope, and "on" just has a wider spike (which, as far as I know, is how PWM is designed).

Is there such thing as a transistor or transistor-like device that can interpret a PWM signal and open/close a "collector" and "emitter" based on the width of the pulse in a PWM signal?

Disclaimer: I am not a professional electrical engineer. There may be a simple answer in front of me that I'm not aware of.

If I'm not providing enough information, let me know.

Answer (score 5):

A PWM with 0% period should be completely off, no spikes. A simple ADC could help with PWM to Digital.

The problem is that while your RC receiver says it's just PWM, it is not. It's a specific protocol that works slightly different. Essentially, it is a PWM signal with 1ms to 2ms pulses at 50hz. A centered pulse is neutral. Even with a push button and not an analog stick, the protocol stays the same.

I highly doubt there is a transistor that does what you want, you would need a custom design or a microcontroller to do what you want. Simple enough to do, read an analog input, determine what the pulse length is, and output to a digital pin the state.

This question is about reverse engineering a product that does just that:
[Nano Electric Receiver Switch - Circuit Components](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/90598/nano-electric-receiver-switch-circuit-components/90671#90671)
You may want to read it *hint hint*

Comment: I haven't done anything with RC receivers but is there a particular reason you'd recommend an analog input over a digital input? I thought that might have made measuring the pulse length a bit easier / more accurate.

Comment: Analog measurement is simply useless in this case, I'm afraid. Even if you low-passed it, you wouldn't get much range on the ADC input.

Comment: @Dzarda - Not true. There are lots of analog topologies you could use here that *would* work. You could do something with an integrator and a sample and hold fed into a comparator, or have a flip-flop driven by the falling edge of the pulse that is fed from a similar integrator driven by the pulse length, and reset by the input being low, or a number of other topologies.  There are *lots* of analog solutions to this issue.

Comment: It's important to remember that the RC PPM protocols were designed for analog systems, since it dates back before computers and MCUs were really available (just discrete logic and analog).

Comment: For what's it's worth, if you *have* a MCU, using an analog input is stupid, but there is no reason to necessarily bother with a MCU.

Comment: Good point. I seriously need to get more familiar with this analog thing :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my understanding of the question and the requirements:

There is an RC receiver that outputs a PWM signal, but apparently not a perfect one, as it generates a brief pulse even for a zero PWM value. This could be because:

- The "PWM signal" output is set to, or only provides, a hobby servo control signal, as described in the [answer by Passerby](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/98592/14004)
- The PWM signal does provide a full range PWM duty cycle, or can be configured to do so, i.e. a DC motor speed control output mode, which many RC ESCs support, however the lowest duty cycle value is not true zero, but a brief spike. This is *not* how PWM is designed, it is probably a glitch.

The requirement appears to be either:

1. The 24 Volt device is desired to come on whenever the PWM duty cycle is non-zero
2. The 24 Volt device should turn on when the PWM duty cycle passes a preset value, say around 50% duty cycle, with the exact threshold being non-critical.

**First step:** Examine whether the RC receiver supports different output modes for servo control and DC motor speed control - possibly on different pins. If yes, switch to the motor speed control mode. If not, consider getting a different receiver that does.

**Second step:** Once DC motor speed control is enabled, use an RC filter at the input to simply filter out any spikes smaller than the desired "Switch it on" duty cycle.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzjv8o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above circuit has the added advantage of allowing the target load to be switched even if the ESC concerned only supports servo control: One would have to tweak the potentiometer and capacitor values to achieve triggering at a suitable servo threshold.

No simple formula can be determined, as RC servo signals can vary widely in their clock speed, since the RC servo is concerned only with the pulse on duration, between 1 and 2 ms, typically. Clock speeds can vary from as low as 10 Hz (newer digital RC servos) to 100 Hz or higher.

Answer (score 0):

The reply by Anindo is great, and this circuit works except one small change. I added a low-drop diode to the input, as my receiver was setting line to 0 and thus discharging the capacitor through relatively low input resistor.

The non-zero-wide pulse is not a glitch, that's by design of r/c protocol (there are 8 slots within 20ms interval, each pulse is from 1 to 2 ms (from 0 to 100% respectively) wide and there are 0.25 ms gaps between pulses. Longer gap denotes next sequence. The receiver basically splits this PPM signal with a counter IC into 8 channels.